# Changing link text and hiding a link with one click

Tags: jquery, text, hyperlink

I really need some guidance here.

I have 3 links with 3 different Ids: btn1, btn2, & btn3.
When I click btn2, I want to change the link text on btn2 & btn3, and hide btn1.
When I click btn2 again, I want to revert back to the original text on btn2 & btn 3, and show btn1.

I have started this in jsfiddle and tried various options, but I am really stumped. Can someone please give me some direction? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/squirc77/EQFRY/>

Comment: Im gonna go out on a limb and say you need to create variables and change the HTML based on the click action.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, you didn't say what the text should be in btn3 so I swapped out 'Reset' and 'Clear' in my example:

```
$('#btn2').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() == 'Search & Save Filter'){
        $this.text('Filter Saved');
        $('#btn3').text('Reset');
        $('#btn1').hide();
    } else {
        $this.text('Search & Save Filter');
        $('#btn3').text('Clear');
        $('#btn1').show();
    }
});
```

Updated version of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQFRY/3/)

Comment: Syon, thank you so much! I hope on on the verge of getting this ... it's still the variables and the if statements that cause me to freeeze. I so appreciate your help! Best.

Comment: @squirc77 No problem, if this helped out please accept it as an answer by clicking the check mark to the left. :)